# Need explanation on specific XSS attack vector

Tags: xss

So my school website has been hacked cos my professor got XSS-ed. So I found that attacker used this XSS attack vector

```
<img src="<img src=search"/onerror=alert("Xss")//">
```

Can anyone explain me how this vector works , and how do you suggest I setup my site against further XSS attacks. Why img inside img tag?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, he is ending your src tag and then inserting his own onerror handler. The onerror gets called when the image cannot be loaded. You can prevent this from escaping all user input - expect that every user is trying to hack your site.

In PHP, you could do this by using:

`strip_tags($_POST['val']):`

Comment: No, strip_tags() doesnt solve the problem, because in many cases xss depends on contexts. See the owasp xss prevention cheat sheet. An xss in an HTML attribute can work without tags.

Comment: Thanks for answering yes i know Javascript events and HTML , but img inside img confused me , Erlend , thanks for OWASP , great source of info.